# Stream android to android

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I want to buffer an audio from My Android phone via wifi and all the other android phones having my app should receive the audio if they are in the same network. can i get a way to send buffers from android. My code i copied from some link. Not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button startButton,stopButton,listenButton;

public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
    AudioRecord recorder;

private int sampleRate = 8000;   
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
    private boolean status = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
     stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
     listenButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.listen_button);

     startButton.setOnClickListener(startListener);
     stopButton.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
     listenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VoiceReceiveActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     minBufSize += 2048;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS","Recorder released");
    }


};

private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
                startStreaming();           
    }
};



public void startStreaming()
{
    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);


                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");
                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");


                recorder.startRecording();


                InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5");
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];


                while (status == true)
                {
                    Log.i("TAG",""+sendData.length);
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 50005);
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
                }

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
}
```

}

Need help. Thank u in advance

Comment: Do you able to create buffer?

Comment: Its just A thing i didn't even understood the code. Is there any sample or good example for it.

Comment: You need to tell us WHAT is "not working" otherwise we have no idea how to actually help you.