# android to android audio live streaming

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I have a plan to develop an instrument app, when we shake the android phone, it will produce "angklung" (Google it) sound.

**THE PROBLEM:**

> How to make one android phone can share its produced sound (by shake
>   gesture) to the other android phones having my application?

The connection that I want to use is mobile data connection and wi-fi.

I think this person has the same problem, but I don't know how to communicate with him. [Stream android to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698820/stream-android-to-android)
But there is no help..

I need solution/example/suggestion for this problem. So far I succeed to produce the "angklung" sound when it is shaken.

I have no idea how to start this application. I've searched in the internet but there is no help :(

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would give you the suggestion of streaming the audio data to a server and beaming that to other android devices (that are registered to your app). As the question/issue you have asked are way bigger than couple of lines code, hence am pointing you to some good resources, dig those deep & good luck.

- [Live-stream video from one android phone to another over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi)
- [Stream Live Android Audio to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server)

Comment: I've already tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server, but I confused where to put the "Server Code". Is it also coded in Android Studio? The problem here, I don't know where/how to built the server for receiving the sound.... thank you very much

Comment: Then you should read about the server-client protocol first, for server part, you can write the code in plain java(not mandatorym you can use any lang you are comfortable with) and use some editor(netbean, eclipse) as per your comfort zone.Interesting part is, the link i and you mentioned here contained both server and client part, so you just need to config them!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try now.

Comment: Good luck for your try, and don't forget to accept the answer as that will help other visitors here who are seeking solutions.

Comment: What should be configured for the server and client part? There is no progress in this part. Those resources can't be compiled in my eclipse. It showed some errors. Thank you for your help.